How to convert ui.Image to a png encoded Uint8List in Flutter in the background?
This issue has been haunting me for weeks now. It sounds simple, but I have tried every imaginable workaround I could come up with. Nothing worked.
The problem:
I have an ui.Image image. I can display this image in the widget etc. without issues. However I need to upload it to a server, and it is a high resolution 100MB image (and I have 20 of them...) Therefore, I NEED to compress it before upload. The image has to be compressed in a lossless format (because requirements) and therefore I have chosen PNG. Since this conversion takes about 1 minute, doing it on the main thread is a no go. It completely freezes the UI. The good news are that the user has to fill in a lot of forms after selecting the image, and this normally takes around 15 minutes. Therefore I want to do this PNG encoding in the background, and the user won't notice a thing.
My best attempt:
After a lot of hair pulling, I managed to come up with this code, that seemed to work at first. But after checking the image on the server, something is wrong with it. It is gray and 3 times on top of itself. However, this code can actually do the encoding in the background, exactly how I would want it to work:
my main function:
final ui.Image? croppedImage = ....

final img.Image image = await convertUiImageToImage(croppedImage);

final Uint8List encodedImage = await encodeImageInBackground(image);


This function converts the ui.Image to an img.Image. This is because it is not possible to send a ui.Image to an isolate.
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

Future<img.Image> convertUiImageToImage(ui.Image uiImage) async {
  final ByteData? byteData =
      await uiImage.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba);
  if (byteData == null) {
    throw Exception('Failed to convert ui.Image to ByteData');
  }
  final Uint8List uint8List = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  return img.Image.fromBytes(
    width: uiImage.width,
    height: uiImage.height,
    bytes: uint8List.buffer,
  );
}

This code makes it PNG encode it in the background:
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

Uint8List encodeImage(img.Image image) {
  return img.encodePng(image, level: 6);
}

Future<Uint8List> encodeImageInBackground(img.Image image) async {
  return await compute(encodeImage, image);
}

Why this code is bad:
This code totally works, but the image ends up looking like some alien thing, which is not optimal. I have traced the issue to the convertUiImageToImage. It seem like this:
final ByteData? byteData = await uiImage.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba);
produces something that this: img.Image.fromBytes(.... cannot read properly. So obviously there is some kind of mismatch between them. I have tried all the different options: rawRgba, rawStraightRgba, rawUnmodified, rawExtendedRgba128. My image becomes messed up. Using ui.ImageByteFormat.png works, but that ruins the whole thing since it blocks the main thread for 1 minute.
What now?
So how could one solve this problem? I have spend weeks trying everything imaginable, but nothing have worked. Either I block the main thread, or I make something that turns the images gray and messed up, or flutter complaints that I cannot send XYZ to an Isolate. This issue seemed so easy on the surface but apparently it was not and I am stuck now...
How to convert an ui.Image to a png encoded Uint8List in the background?
I really, really appreciate any help I can get!

use flutter isolate with background task may be help?

Try this code to convert ui.Image to png encoded Uint8List
Future<Uint8List> convertImageToPngBytes(ui.Image image) async {
  final ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  if (byteData == null) {
    print("Error occured");
    return null;
  }
  
  final Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  return pngBytes;
}


The issue is that this will encode the image as PNG, and since it takes the ui.image as an input, it cannot run in an isolate and it will block the main thread. Therefore this code won't cut it :(
